# How to recursively rename files and folder with iconv from Bash

Tags: linux, file, bash, iconv, tr

I have been trying to recursively rename files AND folders with iconv without success, the files are correctly renamed but folders dont.

What I use for files is (works perfect):

```
find . -name * -depth \ -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}/$(iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< ${1##*/})"' -- {} \;
```

What I tried for files AND folders (fail: Only rename folders):

```
find . -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "$(iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< $1)"' -- {} \;
```

ORIGINAL problem:
I just want to bulk rename lots of files to make them "web friendly", thinks like removing spaces, weird characters and so on, currently I have

```
find . -name '*' -depth \
| while read f ; 
do 
mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f"|tr -s ' ' _|tr -d "'"|tr -d ","|tr - _|tr "&" "y"|tr "@" "a")" ;
done
```

Is there any way to do the tr stuff above and the iconv at a single run? because I am talking around 300,000 files to rename, I would like to avoid a second search if possible.

If needed, I am working with Bash 4.2.24

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have perl around, you can probably using [convmv](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/) instead (which is a tool to convert charset in filenames).

Comment: Just to be clear, did you swap the file and file/folder commands? "-type f" would exclude directories.

Comment: @chepner ups, my bad I was trying different setups. Without "-type f" only folders are renamed, but no files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following does everything you want in one pass.

```
# Update: if this doesn't work, use read -d '' instead
find . -print0 | while IFS= read -d '$\000' f ;
do 
  orig_f="$f"
  # Below is pure bash. You can replace with tr if you like
  # f="$( echo $f | tr -d ,\' | tr "$'&'@- " "ya__" )"
  f="${f// /_}"  # Replace spaces with _
  f="${f//\'}"   # Remove single quote
  f="${f//-/_}"  # Replace - with _
  f="${f//,}"    # Remove commas
  f="${f//&/y}"  # Replace ampersand with y
  f="${f//@/a}"  # Replace at sign with a
  f=$( iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< "$f" )
  new_dir="$(dirname $f)"
  new_f="$(basename $f)"
  mkdir -p "$new_dir"
  mv -i "$orig_f" "$new_dir/$new_f"
done
```

The `find` command (no real options needed, other than `-print0` to handle filenames with spaces) will send null-separated file names to the `while` loop (and someone will correct my errors there, no doubt). A long list of assignments utilizing parameter expansion removes/replaces various characters; I include what I think is the equivalent pipeline using `tr` as a comment. Then we run the filename through `iconv` to deal with character set issues. Finally, we split the name into its path and filename components, since we may have to make a new directory before executing the `mv`.

Comment: I use this line:

    mv -i "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "$f"|tr -s ' ' _|tr -d "'"|tr -d ","|tr - _|tr "&" "y"|tr "@" "a")" ;


To successfully rename directory and files without creating an additional one, because I have around 10,000 directories, this approach will create (on worst case) another 10,000 right?

Comment: That is true. It really depends on whether you want to process the directory names with `tr` and `iconv`. If not, you can edit my code to use the original path in the `mv` command, as you are currently doing. Otherwise, you'll need to be prepared to create new directories.

Comment: @chepner I can't seem to get this to work on Ubuntu 10.04. If I understand it correctly `-print0`separates the file names with nulls then the `read -d '$\000'` terminates at each null, yet when I run it on a file tree nothing happens. If I replace the `do ... done` body with just an `echo $f` I get just blank lines out. I started with a straight copy/paste of your code so I don't think it's down to a typo. This is strange (GNU bash, version 4.1.5)

Comment: I think I fixed my usage of `read -d` in another thread. If you use `read -d ''`, it seems to work.

Comment: Should you not reverse the output of `find` with `tac -s ''` so that folders are renamed *after* their content? I am getting bugs with nested folders otherwise.

Comment: I offered a fix in [this alternative answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41375939/3719101). If you don't mind, I'd rather post it as an edit to your post so it'd be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update I offer after [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530797/3719101) to avoid nesting bugs. Reverse the output of `find` with `tac` to act on folders content *before* the folders themselves. This way, there is no need to `mkdir` anymore:

```
echo "renaming:"
find . -print0 | tac -s '' | while IFS= read -d '' f ;
do
    Odir=$(dirname "$f")   # original location
    Ofile=$(basename "$f") # original filename
    newFile=$Ofile
    # remove unwanted characters
    newFile=$(echo $newFile | tr -d ",'\"?()[]{}\\!")
    newFile="${newFile// /_}"  # Replace spaces with _
    newFile="${newFile//&/n}"  # Replace ampersand with n
    newFile="${newFile//@/a}"  # Replace at sign with a
    newFile=$( iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< "$newFile" )
    if [[ "$Ofile" != "$newFile" ]]; then # act if something has changed
      echo "$Odir/$Ofile to"
      echo "$Odir/$newFile"
      mv -i "$Odir/$Ofile" "$Odir/$newFile"
      echo ""
    fi
done
echo "done."
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: you were looking for `find . -depth`